# Asking a short question triggers the quality filter

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I want to ask a question, it is too short, but meets the quality standards. Why do I get this error?

> Your question does not meet the quality standards of site

My question is:

> I want to know when exactly I installed my OS. How can I do that in CentOS 6.4?

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to find a way to make it longer to get past the quality filter... For example, maybe list a few of the things you've checked. Or some system details. This isn't just a way to defeat the filter, it also makes your question better.

But in this case, there is already an answer here: [What is a distro-agnostic way determine the OS install date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35566/what-is-a-distro-agnostic-way-determine-the-os-install-date)

I will note that is the third result when searching for *install date* and the first for *OS install date*.

That search also shows a few related questions, which may also prove helpful:

- [Installation date of Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/installation-date-of-ubuntu/62529#62529)
- [Is there a way to find out when an OS instance was installed on a host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58519/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-when-an-os-instance-was-installed-on-a-host)
- [Ask Ubuntu: How can I tell what date Ubuntu was installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352/how-can-i-tell-what-date-ubuntu-was-installed)